# How can I make a (antd)Sub-Menu in a Horizontal Menu to align right while other menuItems are aligned left?

Tags: reactjs, menu, antd

I want to align right a SubMenu item that is in a Menu component with other Menu Items. So far I have tried style={{float:right}}, however it does not align it, I have placed multiple empty buttons between the other menu Items and mine to push the menu item right, but it keeps fluctuating. I want just this Submenu to be on the right side of the horizontal menu, I am using ReactJS and  Menu component from  "antd": "^2.13.6".
My code is :

```
    return (
        <Menu mode='horizontal'>
            <Menu.Item >
                <Link to='/'>
                    <Icon type='home' /><text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}> Home</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                <Link to='popular'>
                    <Icon type='heart-o' /> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Popular</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                <Link to='upcoming'>
                    <Icon type='like-o' /> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Up Coming</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>


            <Menu.Item>
                <Link to='nowplaying'>
                    <Icon type='rocket' /> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Now Playing</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            
            <SubMenu   style={{float:'right'}}    title={ <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Diana</text>}>
                <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Get Recs</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Dashboard</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="setting:3"  onClick={() => this.logout()}>
                    <Link   to='/'    onClick={() => this.logout()}>
                        <Icon  onClick={() => this.logout()}/> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Logout</text>
                    </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
        </Menu>
    )
```

Here is a picture of what I get when running the code and what I want to get
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPgYH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use styled-components for that, for the easier styling.
here the link : https://styled-components.com/

example (please add the styled-components first) :

```
const StyledSubMenu = styled(SubMenu)`
Float : Right;
`;

function example(){
return (
        <Menu mode='horizontal'>
            <Menu.Item >
                <Link to='/'>
                    <Icon type='home' /><text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}> Home</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                <Link to='popular'>
                    <Icon type='heart-o' /> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Popular</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item>
                <Link to='upcoming'>
                    <Icon type='like-o' /> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Up Coming</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>


            <Menu.Item>
                <Link to='nowplaying'>
                    <Icon type='rocket' /> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Now Playing</text>
                </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            
            <StyledSubMenu style={{float:'right'}}    title={ <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Diana</text>}>
                <Menu.Item key="setting:1">Get Recs</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="setting:2">Dashboard</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="setting:3"  onClick={() => this.logout()}>
                    <Link   to='/'    onClick={() => this.logout()}>
                        <Icon  onClick={() => this.logout()}/> <text style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>Logout</text>
                    </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </StyledSubMenu enter code here>
        </Menu>
    )
}
```